# What is the cause of the Syntax error that prevents this hangman program from running?

Tags: python-3.x

Very basic question. I'm currently trying to code a hangman game. I've copied the code verbatim from the book, or so I thought. I keep running into a syntax error and it's pointing me to the colon after the 1. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Appreciate any help given.

## Check if player has guessed too many times and lost

```
    if len(missedLetters == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
           displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
        print('You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, and the word was "' + secretWord + '"')
        gameIsDone = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parentheses in your if statement.

This is what you have:`if len(missedLetters == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:`

Should be this to fix the syntax error:
`if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:`

Comment: Geez what a rookie mistake. Thank you so much. I was so concerned with the where the syntax error was located I didn't focus on the rest of the code. I'll be sure to really go over the lines in detail before posting a question next time. I appreciate your help.